# How to extract/get a xml attribute values to display

Tags: api, xml, jquery

I am trying to integrate open weather api in my application and I have invoked weather api and it's returned xml response. But when I am trying to get the values it's throwing error like unknown error.

**My code is:**

**js code:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=xml&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data) {
                    /* handle data here */
                    console.log(data);

                    //$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#weather_report');

                    /*var wrapper = $("#weather_report");
                     wrapper.empty();
                     wrapper.append("<div class='city'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");
                     wrapper.append("<div class='day_1'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");*/

                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    /* handle error here */
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**above code returning below format:**

[image]

Could you please suggest me how to get the `xml` values to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
<script type="application/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({

        ...

        success: function(data) {

            ...

            var xml = jQuery( data );

            var nm = xml.find("weatherdata").find("location").find("name").text();

            console.log("City: " + nm);

            //For iterating through `forecast > time` tags, use

            jQuery(xml).find("time").each(function(){
                console.log("Day: " + jQuery(this).attr("day")  );
                console.log("Name: " + jQuery(this).find("symbol").attr("name")  );
            });


            ...

        },

        ...

    });
});

</script>
```

For more examples, check here : [Read AND Process XML by jQuery](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html)

Comment: I have tried above solution and it's returning `xmlDoc` **null** values.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: no luck still  `xmlDoc` returning **null**

Comment: check updated answer and it's working now